# template with enum fails to initialize its member with a POD template argument value

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization

I am trying to create a lightweight template class having a static member initialized with the value provided as template argument( only `enum` are alowed ).

The code below doesn't build saying

```
   error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
   error: provided for ‘template<field_id field_value, 
   inner_type_id innter_type_value>     struct node’
   error: template declaration of ‘field_id m_field_id’
```

The problem seems the first template argument. If I remove 'field_value' and 'inneer_type_value' still doesn't build saying mismatch error.

Can you help me ?
Thanks AFG

```
   enum field_id{ FIELD_ID_1, FIELD_I_2  };
   enum inner_type_id{ INN_ID_1, INN_ID_2  };

    template< enum field_id  field_value
            , enum inner_type_id inner_type_value 
    >struct node{
            static field_id m_field_id;
    };

    template< 
            enum field_id  field_value
            ,enum inner_type_id inner_type_value 
    >
    enum field_id node<
            enum field_id field_value
            ,enum inner_type_id inner_type_value
    >::m_field_id=field_value;

    int main(){
           node<FIELD_ID_1,INN_ID_1> obj;
           assert( obj::m_field_value == FIELD_ID );
    }
```

I am also tyring another different approach, but still I don't get it

```
         template< typename T1, typename T2 >
         struct node;

         template<>
         struct node< enum field_id=FIELD_ID_1, enum inner_type_id=INN_ID_1>{
              static enum field_id m_field_id;
         };             
         note< 
               enum field_id=FIELD_ID_1
              ,enum inner_type_id=INN_ID_1
              >::m_field_id=FIELD_ID1;
```

Comment: Hey! Just add a comment! When I looked this morning one of the response below I was surprised and amazed by a great explanation about why 'enum' should not used as template argument..it was great but was deleted by the poster! What a pitty! I thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end your code probably should look like:

```
enum field_id{ FIELD_ID_1, FIELD_I_2  };
enum inner_type_id{ INN_ID_1, INN_ID_2  };

template<field_id  field_value, inner_type_id inner_type_value>
//       ^ no enum keyword
struct node
{
  static field_id m_field_id;
};

template<field_id  field_value, inner_type_id inner_type_value>
field_id node<field_value, inner_type_value>::m_field_id = field_value;
//            ^ no enum and type

int main(){
  typedef node<FIELD_ID_1,INN_ID_1> my_type;
  assert( my_type::m_field_id == FIELD_ID_1 );
  //               ^ there's only m_field_id member
  my_type obj;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `enum` keyword cannot appear within template - just use the type name:

```
template<field_id field_value, inner_type_id inner_type_value> struct ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: posted an answer that was wrong.
Alternatively, you can make the static field const and define it inline:

```
template<field_id  field_value
        , inner_type_id inner_type_value 
>struct node{
        static const field_id m_field_id=field_value;
};
```

Comment: Hi AndrehJ! DO you mean inlin the struct, right? Being const + inline sohuld go faster..isn'it? Since it is a short structure I assume that gcc will not have any problem in inlining.

Comment: I meant defined and initialized inside the struct or class body. It is possible only with static const members of integral types. Making it const might make it faster in your case, making it inline will probably not make it faster in this case, but it may in other cases. Anyway, the reason I suggested it is simplicity and readability, not speed. Also, if the value is not supposed to change during an object's lifetime, it's a good idea to set the member type to const.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you repeat the types of the template parameters in the instanciation of the static variable? I yould just write:

```
template <field_id field_value, inner_type_id inner_type_value>
field_id node <field_value, inner_type_value>::m_field_id = field_value;
```

Edit: this compile with gcc and works as expected.